# Getting heights of spans with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to center a series of SPANs vertically inside their parent LIs.

The height values returned are all the same which means there must be something wrong with this code as some of the spans are on two lines.

Not sure if getting the height of an inline element (span) is a problem, any suggestions appreciated.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-level-2-item">
    <a href="">
    <span class="menu-item">Text</span>
            </a>
            </li>

<li class="nav-level-2-item">
    <a href="">
    <span class="menu-item">Longer Text</span>
            </a>
            </li>

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navItem = $('li.nav-level-2-item');

    navItem.each(function() {
        var containerHeight = $('li.nav-level-2-item').height();
        var spanHeight = $('span.menu-item').height();
        alert(spanHeight)
        $('span.menu-item').css('top', (containerHeight - spanHeight) / 2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Spans don't have heights

Comment: What is your goal? What are you attempting to do?

Comment: use DIVs instead, @YuriyGalanter is right - span is dimension-less element on its own which updates according to whatever content it surrounds... or even better, utilize your already existing A tags :)

Comment: I've changed the spans to divs to try and diagnose, still can't vertically center whether they are spans or divs.

Comment: @j08691 trying to vertically center the spans inside the parent lis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is applicable to your code, but maybe you could avoid using jQuery altogether by making the `<li>` elements *inline-block* and centering them vertically:

```
li.nav-level-2-item
{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; *zoom: 1; /* IE 6-7 hack */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Or another possible solution:

```
li.nav-level-2-item
{
    display: table;
}

li.nav-level-2-item a
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For additional CSS-only solutions, check out http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align and http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I had over complected matters by going straight in for a jquery solution. It was possible to achieve with pure css ...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Making your span a [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) element will give it `height`:

```
<style> span.menu-item { display:block /* or inline-block */; } </style>
```

As an alternative, you could change the span to be one of the native [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements).

Comment: I should have included the css in the code but thankyou for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the goal is, but I do have an answer for why the alert is always the same. You're iterating the `li` elements with `.each()`, but on each iteration, you aren't referencing the current item, so you always retrieve the height of the first matching element. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5uwuQ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navItem = $('li.nav-level-2-item');

    navItem.each(function() {
        var containerHeight = $(this).height();
        var spanHeight = $('span.menu-item', this).height();
        console.log(spanHeight)
    });
});
```

Vertical centering of menu items is probably going to be easier by setting the `line-height`.